# Multiple Group Representations using Cayley's Thm

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, permutations

I know that an abstract group can be made isomorphic to a subgroup of a symmetric group, by using a Cayley table for that abstract group. However, what is a technique for getting another permutation group representation of an abstract group?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All *transitive* representations of a group $G$ are obtained, in a generalization of Cayley's, by letting $G$ act on the cosets of a subgroup $H$.

Now a not necessarily transitive representation can be split into its *orbits*, on each of which $G$ acts transitively.

Comment: Thank you, so is the representation formed from the Cayley table of the group, naming a permutation after the action of an element of the group on the other elements still based off the action of a $\mathb {G} $ on the cosets of  some subgroup $\mathb {H } $?

Comment: I believe what you are saying is correct.